# hibernate AttributeAccessor annotation example

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm trying to debug a `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException` caused via a `java.lang.ClassCastException` in the `BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter` class

To do this I'm trying to specify my own PropertyAccessor with annotations in Hibernate (4.3.1.Final)

My code is:

```
   @Id
   @Column(name="id", updatable=false, nullable=false)
   @Type(type = "mypackage.CustomHibernateIntLongType")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @AttributeAccessor("mypackage.DiagnosticAccessor")
   public Long getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(Long _id) {
      this.id = _id;
   }
```

The class `mypackage.DiagnosticAccessor` implements  org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor`

Hibernate doesn't seem to pay any attention to the `@AttributeAccessor` annotation.

I tried putting in a bogus value for the `@AttributeAccessor` and it doesn't even complain.

Does anyone have an example of this working, is there some other configuration option that I should be setting?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: in the end to get the diagnostic information that I wanted I downloaded the hibernate core final (4.3.5) dowloaded the source for the files that I wanted to get diagnostic information (BasicPropertyAccessor, AbstractEntityTuplizer, PojoEntityTuplizer, DefaultFlushEntityEventListener among others) and then compiled my own edited version of those files against the hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar  jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar jar files then updated the core-4.3.5.Final.jar with a jar -uf hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar org/hibernate/property/*.class etc for the packages with updated class files

Comment: the actual problem was that caused the original ClassCastException was that I had an entity bean with dubious naming for accessor methods.  Which means in concrete terms an Account entity with the following methods Agent getAgent(), void setAgent(Agent), boolean isAgent().  It seems that the Getter in the AbstractEntityTuplizer was calling the isAgent() method rather than the getAgent() method, hence later on down the line it was trying to set the Agent as "true" i.e. the result of isAgent, rather than Agent - the result of getAgent.  Hope that saves someone the time it took me